# Adding an object to a fabric.Canvas without dispatching the `object:added` event

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way of adding an object to a `fabric.Canvas` instance without dispatching the `object:added` event?

Currently I'm forced to use the following ugly approach:

```
var dispatchObjectAdded = true;

canvas.on('object:added', function () {
    if (!dispatchObjectAdded) {
        return;
    }

    // handle event..
});


// add normally with dispatch
canvas.add(object);

// add without dispatch
dispatchObjectAdded = false;
canvas.add(object);
dispatchObjectAdded = true;
```

This works because the `object:added` event is dispatched synchronously, but I'm sure there's a better way – I just can't find what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom property on your object, and check in the event handler if the object that triggered the event has that property.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5KKQ2/636/) is a small `fiddle` example.